# Search box broken on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some beauty search box with css.

On chrome, this works fine, but on FF the search button is broken..

```
    <form class="form-wrapper cf" action="" method="post">
        <input type="search" placeholder="O que voce procura?" required>
        <button type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
    </form>
```

my input field css:

```
    /* Form text input */
    .form-wrapper input {
        width: 230px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 30px;
        padding-top:5px\9;
        float: left;    
        font: 16px 'Maven Pro', Arial, Tahoma, serif;
        color:#959595;
        border: 0;
        background: #eee url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
        background-position:5px center;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
    }
    .form-wrapper input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background: #fff url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
        background-position:5px center;
        /*box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;*/
    }
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NeRFC/

Open on Chrome and on Firefox to see the problem

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removed the width from .form-wrapper and it seems to work.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is best eh?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the mozilla rule to .form-wrapper input :

```
-moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
```

Also, try to comment properly those lines:

In .form-wrapper input :

```
background: #eee url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
```

To

```
#background: eee url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
```

In .form-wrapper input:focus :

```
background: #fff url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
```

To

```
#background: fff url(imagens/lupa.png) no-repeat;
```

Maxime

Comment: Maxime, the `#eee` or `#fff` it not coment line, but is color abbreviation for: `#eeeeee` or `#ffffff`

Comment: Right! Confused by the synthax highlighter.. Sorry :)